# Why is jQuery .prop() not working for 'allowfullscreen'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, prop

According to the documentation, the jQuery [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) method only works for `selectedIndex`, `tagName`, `nodeName`, `nodeType`, `ownerDocument`, `defaultChecked` and `defaultSelected`.

But as far as I checked and tried, it is not working for the iFrame attribute `allowFullscreen`.

However, this attribute is boolean, so if I want to set it to either work or not, it is not possible to do so with jQuery `.attr()`, since the attribute is active as long as *any* value is set. So the only way is to either set the attribute or remove it (again) completely which is at least not the optimal way to go.

---

**Currently, I need to set it as follows:**

```
allowFullscreen ? $iframe.attr('allowFullscreen', 'true') : $iframe.removeAttr('allowFullscreen');
```

**But it is somehow not working to normal/easy/logical way:**

```
$iframe.prop('allowfullscreen', allowFullscreen);
```

---

### **Is this a bug or is this somehow intended?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons, the distinction between HTML attributes and HTML properties is messy.  XHTML, being actual XML, did *properties* like `disabled="disabled"` so that they would parse as valid XML.  Luckily, HTML5 saved us from that hell.

The MDN documentation refers to HTML properties (like **disabled**) as "Boolean" attributes.

However, **allowfullscreen** is referenced as having a value that can be set to true rather than being a "Boolean" attribute.  In other words, **allowfullscreen** is an attribute not a property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes

> **allowfullscreen**
>   This attribute can be set to true if the frame is allowed to be placed into full screen mode by calling its Element.requestFullscreen() method. If this isn't set, the element can't be placed into full screen mode.

"Boolean" is not mentioned.  The value of "true" is another giveaway...

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute

> **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

If properties are ducks, **allowfullscreen** looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, but is **not** actually a duck.

Comment: Thank you very much - at least now I can understand what is going on here.

Answer (score -1):

This will set your attribute to true / false, depending on your allowFullScreen var.

```
$iframe.attr('allowFullScreen', allowFullScreen);
```

So you will have attribute with values true or false, and you can check them like:

```
var isAll = ($iframe.attr('allowFullScreen') == 'true');
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but this results in `<iframe allowfullscreen="false">` which de facto **enables** fullscreen for the iframe, since it doesn't matter whether the html attribute value is *true* or *false* - what matters is only whether the attribute itself is there - or not.